# A loop unexpectedly goes running infinitely in the Bash script

Tags: bash, macos, shell

I have created a bash script on my Mac named `Armstrong.sh`.

This is a function which checks for a number to be an armstrong number.

```
# This function works properly
armstrong() {

    num=$1    # Making a copy of the received number.
    sum=0     # This will store the sum of cubes of each digit from $num



    while [ $num -gt 0];      # This loop runs while $num is greater than 0
    do
        temp=`expr $num % 10`                      # Extract the last digit of the number
        sum=`expr $sum + $temp \* $temp \* $temp`  # Cube the last digit and add it to $sum
        num=`expr $num / 10`                       # Remove the last digit of the number
    done



    if [ $sum -eq $1 ];   # If $sum == $1, i.e., If the number is armstrong
    then   
        echo "$1 is an armstrong number"        # print the number
    else
        echo "$1 is not an armstrong number"
    fi
}
```

When I write the following code,

```
armstrong 1     # this is an armstrong number
armstrong 153   # This is an armstrong number
armstrong 24    # This is not an armstrong number
```

Then it's output is as follows,

```
1 is an armstrong number
153 is an armstrong number
24 is not an armstrong number
```

This was good till now.

But the **PROBLEM** lies here.
When I try to print all armstrong numbers within a range using a loop like this:

```
# Accept start and end point of the range
echo -n "Enter start = "
read start
echo -n "Enter end = "
read end

# Loop from start to end point and call the armstrong() function
for ((num = $start; num <= $end; num++))
do
    armstrong $num    # Calling the function.
done
```

So my questions are:
**1>** How do I get the loop working as desired?
**2>** Is there any way I can write the code without using `$temp` in `armstrong()` function?
Just like `sum += Math.pow(num%10, 3);` in Java?
**3>** Please give me a cleaner way to write the `armstrong` function.

Comment: BTW, since you're targeting bash, consider using math contexts more -- `if (( sum == $1 ))` is a bit easier to read than `if [ "$sum" -eq "$1" ]`.

Comment: ...likewise, the modern POSIX sh syntax is: `temp=$((num % 10 ))`, and `sum=$((sum + temp * $temp * $temp))`; there's no need to use `expr` for math unless targeting pre-POSIX Bourne (which is almost unheard of these days).

Comment: Consider using http://shellcheck.net/ for static analysis of your shell scripts, btw.

Comment: err, `sum=$((sum + temp * temp * temp))`; no need for all the `$`s inside of a math context, unless you care about behavior of unset variables (without a `$`, unset variables are treated as 0; with a `$`, they generate an error).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your function uses the variable `num` without declaring it local, so it's changing the same shell-global variable referred to by the loop, thus resetting the loop's state and preventing it from completing.

Inside the function, change

```
num=$1
```

to

```
local num=$1
```

...and, ideally, do the same for all other variables inside of functions unless you explicitly want your function to modify variables in global scope.

Comment: Thanks. It worked. :) By the way should I make `$sum` variable `local` too?

Comment: @Aditya, yes, you should also make `sum` and `temp` local as well. Another way to do this is just to put a line at the top of the function: `local num sum temp`

Comment: @Aditya, ...btw, unlike perl, the `$` isn't part of the variable's name in shell; instead, it's an expansion operator (used, as the name implies, when expanding the variable for its contents), but isn't used in cases where a variable is referred to without expanding it.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy Thanks charles. But is there any way to return `true` from `armstrong()` if the number is armstrong, else `false` rather than printing it in the function itself? as in, `return true` or `return false` in Java?

Comment: @Aditya, `return 0` for true, or `return 1` for false. (Any nonzero 7-bit value will work as false, but 1 is conventional). Having done this, you can write logic such as `if armstrong 5; then ...` and it will behave as you'd expect.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy Can you please explain how good is the `return` statement in bash?

Comment: @Aditya, what does that question mean? What makes a "return" statement good or bad? It faithfully implements the POSIX specification, as given at http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009604599/utilities/return.html

Comment: @CharlesDuffy I mean, I read it somewhere on the internet that `return` statements in bash scripts do not return values as in C or CPP or Java. So how would I return true or false? I tried ur way, but I am getting unexpected results.

Comment: @Aditya, as I said, you return `0` for true (which is what the C constant `EXIT_SUCCESS` hardcodes) or `1` for false (which is equal to the C constant `EXIT_FAILURE`). Bash's return values work like C's exit status, and have the same limitations on their valid range. If you're getting "unexpected results", ask a separate question with enough information to reproduce.

Comment: You can't `return true` or `return false` because true and false aren't values in bash, they're *commands* (and, just as with C's exit status, return value is constrained to a single-byte integer). The `true` command exits with status 0, and the `false` command exits with status 1.

Answer (score 1):

The function is only checking for armstrong numbers of 3 digit length.

Armstrong numbers, also known as [Narcissistic Numbers](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Narcissistic_number), are numbers that are the sum of each digit raised to the power of the number's length.

As @CharlesDuffy pointed out, to avoid unexpected behavior, variables inside the function should be defined as `local` variables.  Unless, of course, they need to be accessed globally.

Also, when using `bash`'s limited integer expressions, larger numbers will break any `test` or calculation of the number.

To fix that, you can use [pattern matching](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Pattern-Matching.html) for tests, and [`bc`](http://www.gnu.org/software/bc/manual/bc.html) for calculations:

```
armstrong() {

    # Initialize all local variables
    local num=$1 sum=0 num_digits=${#1}

    # Make sure number is greater than 0
    while [[ $num == [1-9]* ]]
    do
        # Raise the last digit to the length of $num and add it to $sum
        sum=$(echo "$sum + (($num % 10)^$num_digits)" | bc)

        # Remove the last digit of the number
        num=$(echo "scale=0; $num / 10" | bc)
    done

    if [[ $sum == $1 ]]
    then   
        echo "$1 is an armstrong number"
    else
        echo "$1 is not an armstrong number"
    fi

}
```

Alternatively, you could iterate over each single digit in the `num` variable using [parameter expansion](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Shell-Parameter-Expansion.html):

```
 for ((i=0;i<=$((num_digits-1));i++)); do
     sum=$(echo "$sum + (${num:$i:1}^$num_digits)" | bc)
 done
```